# Porque no se generan la UK a nivel de tabla con uniqueConstraints (java,Oracle)?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Estoy comenzando el desarrollo de un App en Java-Hibernate-Oracle y necesito agregar restricciones de varias columnas, a la vez de nombrar correctamente cada restricción. Para ello tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="PROVEEDORES",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = {"RUT"}, name = "UK_Proveedores_RUT"),
                @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = {"NF", "RS"}, name = "UK_Proveedores_NF_RS"),
                @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = {"MAIL"}, name = "UK_Proveedores_MAIL")
        }       
)
public class Proveedor implements Serializable { 
...
```

Configuración de persistence.xmls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Gastronomia_EJB">   
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/GASTRONOMIA_DS</jta-data-source> 
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>       
        <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

Al momento de correr el server se crea la tabla PROVEEDORES pero sin ninguna restricción.
Alguien que pueda ayudarme, por favor?
Gracias!